# How can I Configure localhost and remote server with single config file

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, remote-server

I'm using different configuration files in my `localhost` and remote server. It makes me very uncomfortable because every time I need to change the server name, password and db name.
Is that any other to have single config method to connect both `localhost` and remote server?

This is my config file:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: you could just make the settings identical for both. or just detect which is which and have and if\else clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the host run time.

The following code will check the host whenever the file runs.

And depending upon the host, it will use different credentials.

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if ($host == 'localhost') {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";
}
else {
    $servername = "REMOTE_HOST";
    $username = "REMOTE_USERNAME";
    $password = "REMOTE_PASSWORD";
    $dbname = "REMOTE_DB";
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check superglobal `$_SERVER` array's `HTTP_HOST` value which stores current host.

It is better to use `strpos` instead of comparison. Your `HTTP_HOST` can have a specified non-default port like `localhost:8080`. It is OK since your remote host will very unlikely contain `localhost` in it's name.

```
<?php
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'localhost') !== false)
    { 
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "myDB";
    } else {
        $servername = "10.11.12.13";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "P@$$w0rd";
        $dbname = "myDBName";            
    }

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set in your virtual host the environment

```
    SetEnv environment {production/development}
```

So your virtual host might looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/httpd"
    ServerName mysite.local
    ServerAlias mysite.local
    SetEnv environment production
</VirtualHost>
```

php code:

```
<?php
if (getenv('environment') == 'production') {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "production-username";
    $password = "production-password";
    $dbname = "myDB";
} else {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$conn->close();

?>
```